# Trying to understand mysqli, need an array with one column as keys and one column as value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Ok, so, my problem is I have a table with posts, each post has a category id but not the category name. i have another table of category id's with the category name. so i want to loop through the posts and echo the category name. I was thinking I'd just put another mysqli query inside the while loop so

```
while($row_post = mysqli_fetch_array($result_post)){

query_post_cat = "SELECT category_name FROM categories WHERE category_id = " . $row_post["category_id"];
result_post_cat = mysqli_query($link, $query_post_cat);
$category_name = something here not sure

 echo $row_post["post_title"] . $category_name;
}
```

Can't figure out where to go from there. The other way I thought is to do the category table outside the while loop and somehow make an assoc array with the cat id as the key and cat name as the value and just echo

```
category_name[$row_post["category_id"]]
```

etc in the while loop.

Aside from this I'm pretty sure the way I'm using mysqli is not ideal, when I  see other peoples code it seems they are using the -> object operator a lot and I have no idea what that is or how it works and cant find any information on it. So I'm pretty lost as you can see

Thanks your help

Comment: 1) You have missed $ with variable name 2) you should write while **$row mysqli_fetch_row($result_post_cat))**;

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: `i'd just put another mysqli query inside the while loop` is never good idea

Comment: As far as using the -> operator for mysqli, it's just a different style: OOP (object-oriented programming) vs procedural style.  You can read more about both at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php

Answer (score 2):

If you run a query with a join, you can get the data from both tables at once, like this:

```
SELECT post_table.*, categories.category_name FROM post_table INNER JOIN categories ON post_table.category_id = categories.category_id;
```

You can look up more on this at: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be as below:-

```
while($row_post = mysqli_fetch_array($result_post)){
  // missed $ below line
  $query_post_cat = "SELECT category_name FROM categories WHERE category_id = {$row_post['category_id']}";
  $result_post_cat = mysqli_query($link, $query_post_cat);
  // use mysqli_fetch_row below
  $category_name = mysqli_fetch_row($result_post_cat));

  echo $row_post["post_title"] . $category_name;
}
```

Better way is to use mysql [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) in your query to get desired records in single shot.